# How to start tomcat in Linux Ubuntu from Java or Scala program

Tags: server, nginx

I have one requirement where I need to start tomcat, nginx, kafka etc from scala or java program, I am able to check through java program that if they are running or not using `ps-ef| grep name` but if they are not running I want them to start itself from java or scala program, I tried this for tomcat

```
val pr = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(Array[String]("/home/administrator/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin","-c","echo def123@| sudo -S startup.sh"))
```

but its not working, so can something plz help me out here!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be the usage of `sudo`. You need `gksudo`.

---

A simple Scala example

```
package com.askubuntu.users.aamir

import scala.sys.process._

object startProcess {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Process("ls -la")!
  }
}
```

or with `sudo`-rights (you need `gksudo`)

```
package com.askubuntu.users.aamir

import scala.sys.process._

object startProcess {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Process("gksudo nautilus")!
  }
}
```

and with a little bit more Java

```
package com.askubuntu.users.aamir

object startProcess {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Runtime.getRuntime.exec(Array[String]("gksudo","nautilus"));
  }
}
```

---

And here is a Java method to start a process

```
package com.askubuntu.users.aamir;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class startProcess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader in;
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/home/administrator/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin","-c","echo def123@| sudo -S startup.sh"});
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String text;
            while ((text = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(text);
                out.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
package com.askubuntu.users.aamir;

import java.io.IOException;

public class startProcess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "gksudo","nautilus", "/tmp" });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried its not working

Comment: I only needed to start the tomcat don't need any stream

Comment: yes,  I tried this `val pr = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("/home/administrator/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin/startup.sh");
 val res = convertStreamToString(pr.getInputStream);
if(res.isEmpty) {
  print( "nothing" )
} else {
  print( res )
}
 def convertStreamToString( is:java.io.InputStream):String= {

  val s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A")
  if(s.hasNext) s.next()  else ""
}` its printing nothing

Comment: but its returning empty string, and also when i checked `localhost:8080` in browser it was not showing apache homepage'

Comment: whatever man, `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("/home/administrator/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin/startup.sh` itself is not working..

Comment: can u plz explain why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29187/discussion-between-a-b-and-aamir).